# Storage and re-computation of Intermediate / Weight / Back-propagated Gradients

Tags: deep-learning, backpropagation, gradient

I need to track the computation and storage of different parts of my network training.
To be on the same page, let's assume the simple following scenario (biases omitted)
[image]

### **Questions**

**Local Gradients**
- Are the intermediate gradients **always** stored in memory until they are consumed in the backward pass, being eliminated after that? Or is there an option to **not storing but recompute** them when needed during the backward pass?
- How can I access those values right after they are computed in the forward pass? Is there anything similar to `self.layer_i.weight.data.numpy()`?

**Back-Propagated Error**
- Is it right the theoretical understanding of back-propagated error?
In the [Glorot and Bengio paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) *(equations 13 and 14 in particular)* they make a different analysis for weight gradients and back-propagated gradients and I want to make sure I got that right before analyzing anything. 
- Is it possible again to access directly these values from the networks attributes? Something like required_grad = True that could allow me to use `self.layer_i.weight.data.numpy()` for the input instead of for the parameters (weights)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can answer the first question:

Recomputing gradients to save memory makes sense. This is usually called "gradient checkpointing". [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06174) is one such paper, although there are many. You pay a small time penalty for a large savings in memory. The key is not to recompute *all* the gradients, but rather to save the gradients at strategic "checkpoint" layers in the computation graph, so that you only ever need to recompute a small number of gradients.